# Discord JS - How to react multiple times to the same embed with same emoji?

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to react with the same emoji multiple times. The above code react only once. Not sure why

```
client.on("messageReactionAdd", (reaction, user) => {
    console.log(reaction.emoji)
    const message = reaction.message;

    const embeds = message.embeds;
    //return if no embeds or if another user reacted instead of the bot itself
    if(!embeds.length || user.id !== message.author.id) return;

    const firstEmbed = embeds[0];
    //react same
    Promise.all([
        message.react(''),
        message.react(''),
        message.react(''),

    ])
});
```

Comment: Any user on discord can only react to a message one time, be it a user or a bot. Otherwise, stuff like poll or giveaway reactions wouldn't work. You can react with multiple emojis but I'm not sure you can do what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1):

Reactions are singular actions. Amount of reactions is calculated using the amount of user/bot accounts called the reaction with specific emoji. So you can react using multiple emojis, but only one time per one emoji. So, this is simply restriction on the side of the API.

There is no direct mentions about in both Discord.js and Discord API docs. But it's just work this way.